# Fail2ban ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash: ip timeout -l

Tags: fail2ban

I have over 2.5 million ssh attempts and fail2ban and only a few thousand ip's blocked. The find time was set to 600, max retries 4, and bantime -1. The server is physically present. I changed the jail.local and tried restarting `systemctl restart fail2ban` and it starts with a whole bunch of errors. I reverted jail.local back how it was and tried again and still get the same errors. I deleted some of the `secure` logs and tried again and it seemed to start but when I reviewed the status the errors were still there and almost nothing is being blocked.

I get the error `Fail2ban ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash: ip timeout -l` followed by a whole bunch of subsequent failures that I think are precipitated by the first.

I tried stopping, uninstalling and reinstalling fail2ban and still have the same initial error followed by a whole bunch of errors.

**My questions are:**

**1. Why/how does ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash timeout?**

**2. How can I properly reinstall fail2ban so that maybe it might block something?**

**3. If there's no working answer on the first two, can't the ip blocking rules be programmed outside of fail2ban?**

fail2ban.log:

```
2019-05-12 21:08:35,823 fail2ban.action         [1730]: ERROR   ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout -1
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- stdout: ''
2019-05-12 21:08:35,823 fail2ban.action         [1730]: ERROR   ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout -1
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- stderr: "ipset v6.29: Syntax error: '-1' is out of range 0-4294967\n\x1b[91mError: COMMAND_FAILED\x1b[00m\n"
2019-05-12 21:08:35,824 fail2ban.action         [1730]: ERROR   ipset create fail2ban-sshd hash:ip timeout -1
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -m set --match-set fail2ban-sshd src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable -- returned 13
2019-05-12 21:08:35,824 fail2ban.actions        [1730]: ERROR   Failed to start jail 'sshd' action 'firewallcmd-ipset': Error starting action
2019-05-12 21:08:35,825 fail2ban.actions        [1730]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 218.92.0.147
2019-05-12 21:08:46,771 fail2ban.transmitter    [1730]: WARNING Command ['start', 'sshd'] has failed. Received OperationalError('database is locked',)
2019-05-12 21:08:51,787 fail2ban                [1730]: CRITICAL Unhandled exception in Fail2Ban:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fail2ban/server/jailthread.py", line 66, in run_with_except_hook
    run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fail2ban/server/filtersystemd.py", line 290, in run
    self.jail.putFailTicket(ticket)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fail2ban/server/jail.py", line 195, in putFailTicket
    self.database.addBan(self, ticket)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fail2ban/server/database.py", line 96, in wrapper
    return f(self, self._db.cursor(), *args, **kwargs)
OperationalError: database is locked
2019-05-12 21:08:56,800 fail2ban.actions        [1730]: ERROR   Failed to get all bans merged, jail 'sshd': database is locked
2019-05-12 21:09:01,812 fail2ban.actions        [1730]: ERROR   Failed to get jail bans merged, jail 'sshd': database is locked
2019-05-12 21:09:01,941 fail2ban.action         [1730]: ERROR   ipset add fail2ban-sshd 218.92.0.147 timeout -1 -exist -- stdout: ''
2019-05-12 21:09:01,941 fail2ban.action         [1730]: ERROR   ipset add fail2ban-sshd 218.92.0.147 timeout -1 -exist -- stderr: 'ipset v6.29: The set with the given name does not exist\n'
2019-05-12 21:09:01,942 fail2ban.action         [1730]: ERROR   ipset add fail2ban-sshd 218.92.0.147 timeout -1 -exist -- returned 1
```

systemctl status fail2ban

```
fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-05-12 21:08:46 EDT; 38min ago
     Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
  Process: 1462 ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop (code=exited, status=255)
  Process: 1726 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client -x start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1730 (fail2ban-server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/fail2ban.service
           ├─1599 /usr/bin/python2 -s /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock -p /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid -x -b
           └─1730 /usr/bin/python2 -s /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock -p /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid -x -b

May 12 21:08:24 myHost systemd[1]: Starting Fail2Ban Service...
May 12 21:08:24 myHost fail2ban-client[1726]: 2019-05-12 21:08:24,579 fail2ban.server         [1728]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.9.7
May 12 21:08:24 myHost fail2ban-client[1726]: 2019-05-12 21:08:24,580 fail2ban.server         [1728]: INFO    Starting in daemon mode
May 12 21:08:29 myHost fail2ban-client[1726]: ERROR  NOK: ('database is locked',)
May 12 21:08:34 myHost fail2ban-client[1726]: ERROR  NOK: ('database is locked',)
May 12 21:08:46 myHost fail2ban-client[1726]: ERROR  NOK: ('database is locked',)
May 12 21:08:46 myHost systemd[1]: Started Fail2Ban Service.
[root@myHost /]# fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 7
|  |- Total failed:     46
|  `- Journal matches:  _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     1
   `- Banned IP list:   218.92.0.147
```

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the logs over and over I decided to pay attention to the following line:

```
ERROR   Failed to start jail 'sshd' action 'firewallcmd-ipset': Error starting action
```

This got me to check the `firewalld` log which showed

```
NOT_ENABLED: rule '('-p', 'tcp', '-m', 'multiport', '--dports', 'ssh', '-m', 'set', '--match-set', 'fail2ban-sshd', 'src', '-j', 'REJECT', '--reject-with', 'icmp-port-unreachable')' is not in 'ipv4:filter:INPUT'
```

for each time I tried starting and restarting fail2ban. I searched that error and found https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=60586 which suggested changing adding

```
banaction = iptables-allports
```

to the jails.local file under the sshd section.

I restarted fail2ban and the ip's started getting blocked in a way that was more consistent with my expectations.